# I need to interrupt an autohotkey script and then restart it in a different location.

Tags: autohotkey

```
loop, read, c:\storefile.txt
{
store_select := A_index - 1
sleep, 1000
gosub, selectstore
gosub, login
gosub, makeandorrunreport
gosub, Emailreport
getout: ; label pointer for logging out and moving on
gosub, logout
gosub, startprism
}
pause
```

I want to interrupt that script if it hangs in one of my subrutines, and make it continue from my getout label.

something like a pause toggle that would let me change the execution point of the thread once the pause was over.

Is that possible?

Comment: I would rather worry about your script hanging; also (excessive) usage of goto labels is just bad.

Comment: it only hangs generally when an unexpected error is encountered.  Ill log the error to account for it later, but in the mean time i want to continue with the next loop iteration.  I generally use loops that copy text from a given point on screen and only break when the copied material matches what was expected. But an unexpected error in the software I am controlling can prevent any of my contingencies from firing off.  So i really want a way to force my script to move to the logout label if I detect a hang.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try/catch, and when an error is caught, run a separate script you've composed in advance in the other location, and then kill the original.

**Example:**

```
try  ; Attempts to execute code.
{
    loop, read, c:\storefile.txt
    {
        store_select := A_index - 1
        sleep, 1000
        gosub, selectstore
        gosub, login
        gosub, makeandorrunreport
        gosub, Emailreport
        getout: ; label pointer for logging out and moving on
        gosub, logout
        gosub, startprism
    }
    pause
}
catch e  ; Handles the first error/exception raised by the block above.
{
    Run, Script\from\separate\location.ahk  ; Run script from somewhere else.
    ExitApp ; Kill off the current script.
}
```